# godaddy vps dns setting

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, postfix, godaddy

I have goDaddy Domain with this dns record

```
a   @   107.150.xx.xx   600 seconds     Edit
cname   email   email.secureserver.net  1 Hour  Edit
cname   ftp     @   1 Hour  Edit
cname   www     @   1 Hour  Edit
mx  @   mailstore1.secureserver.net (Priority: 10)  1 Hour  Edit
mx  @   smtp.secureserver.net (Priority: 1)     1 Hour  Edit
ns  @   ns21.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour  
ns  @   ns22.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour
```

as you can see the domain is pointing to a vps with postfix installed (this vps is for web server and email server). I've setup the postfix (via webmin) and successfully sending email, but when i tried to send email from hotmail to my server, it doesn't receiving, and no error in /var/log/maillog

i'm suspecting there's something in the dns that i need to configure

can somebody pin point it for me? thanks

Comment: Fix your MX records.

Comment: can you elaborate more? i'm a bit confuse how to point it. is this correct  mx  @  @ (Priority: 0)  1 Hour

Comment: `as you can see the domain is pointing to a vps with postfix installed` - Really? Where is that evident from the DNS records?

Comment: a   @   107.150.xx.xx   600 seconds     Edit. its pointing to a vps, where the postfix already installed and configured in that vps. (CMIIW)

Comment: How would that be obvious to us?

Comment: what you need then?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands at the moment, the MX records for your domain designate GoDaddy's servers as the email servers for your domain. You need to change the MX records so that they designate your server as the email server for your domain.

Comment: can you give me some example?